How do you mix client and server TypeScript code in an npm-workspaces mono-repo?
I'm trying to have both client and server-side packages in an npm workspaces monorepo, but the definitions for globals such as setTimeout are conflicting. I'm not sure what the best solution is for this.
I've defined a minimal example here.
The client package has a tsconfig with "lib": ["ES2022", "DOM"] in the compiler options, so it has access to the browser global types such as setTimeout. The server package has @types/node declared as a dev-dependency. Running npm install in the root will install @types/node into the root node_modules, making it visible to the client as well, including the conflicting definition of setTimeout. Then building with tsc results in the following error:
packages/client/src/index.ts:2:7 - error TS2322: Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'.

2 const timeout: number = setTimeout(() => {}, 1000);
        ~~~~~~~

I can work around the issue in this case by doing a type cast in the client code, but I'm wondering if there's a more correct way of structuring things that doesn't cause this issue.
